# extract all dependent variables using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
col1    col2    
V1  NULL    
V2  NULL    
V3  V2,V1   
V4  V3,V5   
V5  NULL    
V6  V3,V7   
V7  NULL
```

---

When V4 is selected

```
V4
V3
V5
V2
V1
```

---

When V6 is selected

```
V6
V3
V7
V2
V1
```

When user selects a variable, query should be able to get all dependent variables for that variable and load to temp table. Please let me know if there is a way to do this and I am using Oracle 11g. Thanks in advance

Comment: One way to do this would be a) normalize the database then b) use a recursive CTE. As it is since you have stored multiple values as CSV in columns you will need a function or query to first parse the data and normalize it, then perform recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh...  comma-separated values. Ed Codd wrote about normal forms 46 years ago, yet we can't even get the First Normal Form right.

Anyway: assuming your base table is called INPUTS, you could do something like this. `:col1` is the bind variable, don't forget to assign it first. SQL Developer and Toad will ask you to, but in SQL*Plus you will just get an error if you don't.

```
select       col1
from         inputs
connect by   ',' || prior col2 || ','      like      '%,' || col1 || '%,'
start with   col1 = :col1
;
```